# Convert Number to words in Crystal Report using Crystal Syntax

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm working on the task to convert the number to words using Crystal Report and Crystal syntax as well.
I did well for any amount <100K with the code below but face the problem with amount >100K (in VN currency, we even convert hunderds billions, not only 10K or millions). Could some one helps me to find the way to handle this issue to convert any amount to words .
Thank you in advance for any help from you.

```
//the array value is the wording of number in EN Zero, One, Two, Three...
local stringvar array Array_Items:= ["không","một","hai","ba","bốn","năm","sáu","bẩy","tám","chín"];

local numbervar x;
local numbervar z;
local stringvar strcuaso;
z:=10000;
local numbervar s10k;
local stringvar strs10k;
local numbervar s1k;
local stringvar strs1k;
local stringvar th;
local numbervar stram;
local stringvar strstram;
local numbervar schuc;
local stringvar strschuc;
local numbervar sdonvi;
local stringvar strsdonvi;

local stringvar a;
x:=50031;
strcuaso:=totext(x,2,"");

s10k:=tonumber(left(strcuaso,1));

s1k:=tonumber(mid(strcuaso,2,1));

if((s10k=1)and(s1k=0))then
strs10k:="mười";
if((s10k=1)and(s1k=0))then
strs1k:="nghìn";
if((s10k>1)and(s1k=0))then
strs10k:=totext(Array_Items[s10k+1])+" mươi ";
if((s10k>1)and(s1k=0))then
strs1k:="nghìn";

if((s10k=1)and(s1k>=1))then
strs10k:="mười ";
if((s10k=1)and(s1k>=1))then
strs1k:=totext(Array_Items[s1k+1])+" nghìn ";
if((s10k>1)and(s1k=1))then
strs10k:=totext(Array_Items[s10k+1])+ " mươi ";
if((s10k>1)and(s1k=1))then
strs1k:=" mốt nghìn ";

if(s10k>1)and(s1k>1)then
strs10k:=totext(Array_Items[s10k+1])+ " mươi ";
if(s10k>1)and(s1k>1)then
strs1k:=totext(Array_Items[s1k+1])+" nghìn ";
stram:=tonumber(mid(strcuaso,3,1));
schuc:=tonumber(mid(strcuaso,4,1));
sdonvi:=tonumber(mid(strcuaso,5,1));
strstram:=" "+totext(Array_Items[stram+1])+" trăm ";
if((schuc=0)AND(sdonvi=0))then
th:="A" ;   
if((schuc=0)AND(sdonvi>=1))then
th:="B";
if((schuc=1)and(sdonvi>0))then
th:="C1";
if((schuc=1)and(sdonvi=0))then
th:="C2";
if((schuc>1)and(sdonvi=0))then
th:="D";
if((schuc>1)and(sdonvi=1))then
th:="E";  //strsdonvi="mốt";
if((schuc>1)and(sdonvi>1))then
strsdonvi:=totext(Array_Items[sdonvi+1])
th:="F";

if(th="A")then
strschuc:="";
if(th="A")then
strsdonvi:="";

if(th="B")then
strschuc:="";
if(th="B")then
strsdonvi:=" linh " +totext(Array_Items[sdonvi+1]);

if(th="C1")then
strschuc:="mười ";
if(th="C1")then
strsdonvi:=totext(Array_Items[sdonvi+1]);
if(th="C2")then
strschuc:="mười";
if(th="C2")then
strsdonvi:="";

if(th="D")then
strschuc:=totext(Array_Items[schuc+1])+" mươi " ;
if(th="D")then
strsdonvi:="";

if(th="E")then
strschuc:=totext(Array_Items[schuc+1])+" mươi " ;
if(th="E")then
strsdonvi:=" mốt ";

if(th="F")then
strschuc:=totext(Array_Items[schuc+1])+" mươi";
if(th="F")then
strsdonvi:=totext(Array_Items[sdonvi+1]);

if(x=z)then
a:="Mười nghìn VND"
else
a:=ProperCase(strs10k)+strs1k+strstram+strschuc+strsdonvi+" VND ";
```

Comment: as I'm a new bie so I dont know how to post my code in my post, I post it to G-Doc here https://docs.google.com/document/d/19-Hkso1lfD9TSO1S0djp5Qy9XHNfF_SoVF4sQeXRlLM/edit?usp=sharing , this code works well with amount <100K but with bigger amount, it is difficult to continue .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I can't help with Crystal Report - but you'll get better response from folks who can if you include your code in the question (not in comment and not in external link).  Here are a couple of links that may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you, noted for next question as in fact, the deadline is coming so that I have not enough time to learn /read the guide of Stackoverflow (my bad, sorry).

Comment: I added the code from your link to the question.  It would probably be helpful if you could translate the words in your native language to English though.